# ng-select not showing result on search, but after (on clicking other things or on remove)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select for postal code, on search it will search the API and the search functions works for the code and the area name (only different query on the API search).

```
<ng-select
    formControlName="addressCode"
    placeholder="enter your postal code"
    (search)="search($event)"
    (change)="set($event)"
    [items]="postalCode"
    bindValue="id"
    bindLabel="postalCode"
    labelForId="addressCode"
  >
    <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
      <span>{{ item.name+ '  ' + item.code}}</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm" let-index="index">
      <span>{{ item.name+ '  ' + item.code}}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-select>
```

```
search(event: any) {
    const text = event.term;
    if (!text || text.length < 3) {
      this.postalCode= [];
      return;
    }
    this.searchPostalCode(text)
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(2000)
    )
    .subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      if (Object.keys(result).length === 0) {
        this.postalCode= [];
      } else {
        this.postalCode= result;
      }
      console.log(this.postalCode);
    });
    
  }
```

If the input is the postal code, it works just fine. But if the input is a string, the dropdown gives a 'no items found' until you remove your input with the button or closing the ng-select and opening it again

I checked the API, query and data works completely fine. I checked the function and the subscription, the data went through okay (the console.log at the function shows the actual search result). I removed the ng-template display and used the default option, still the same issue.

The expected result is upon search, the dropdown immediately comes up with the searched result. The actual result is it shows no data first, and after next action (clearing input / closing the search and reopen), then the data comes out

Comment: have you using 'changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,' ?